# Django Rest Framework dynamic field list on Serializer for list of items

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

In django rest framework, it is possible to dynamically remove fields at runtime with a custom `__init__` method on the serializer. I am using this technique to remove certain fields from the serializer depending on the relation of the requesting user and requested resource, as follows:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # get request from context, initialize super class etc.

    if request.user != self.instance.user:
        self.fields.pop('private field')
```

This approach works well when retrieving a single object, but when I am listing objects, the serializer is initialized with a list of items, hence self.instance does not point to a specific instance on init method, hence I can not make the comparison I want.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve what I want when listing objects?

Answer (score 0):

You should call the Serializer with the keyword *many=True* so each element is processed independently, and pass through your custom init. Something like:

```
serialization = MySerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
```

If you don't now if you will handle an element or a list of elements you should either convert the elemente into a list, only receive lists (1 to many) or detect the case and define *many* accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Serializer mixin where you overwrite `to_representation`.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from collections import OrderedDict


class MySerializerMixin(serializers.Serializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        original_representation = super(MySerializerMixin, self).to_representation(instance)
        final_representation = OrderedDict()
        # don't append keys you don't want for serialization
        for k,v in original_representation.iteritems():
            if k not 'something':
                final_representation[k] = v
        return final_representation
```

And use it like this when defining your serializer.

```
class SomeSerializer(MySerializerMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
```

I use something similar to remove all None values but with some adjustments it should also fit your needs.